# Facebook get authorize error on LoginDialogListener IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android, facebook

I´m using this code to put wall message in Facebook, but...not found the DialogListeners:

This is the code of the activity.

I´m use the tutorial: http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

```
public class FacebookPostMessageActivity extends Activity {
  public class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
      saveCredentials(facebook);
      if (messageToPost != null) {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
      }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
      showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
      finish();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
      showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
      finish();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
      showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
      finish();
    }
  }

  private static final String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_stream" };
  private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
  private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
  private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";
  private Facebook facebook;
  private String messageToPost;

  public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
    return editor.commit();
  }

  public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
        .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
    facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    restoreCredentials(facebook);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    if (facebookMessage == null) {
      facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
    }
    messageToPost = facebookMessage;
  }

  public void doNotShare(View button) {
    finish();
  }

  public void share(View button) {
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
      loginAndPostToWall();
    } else {
      postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
  }

  public void postToWall(String message) {
    FacebookPoster fp = new FacebookPoster();
    fp.execute(message, null, null);
  }

  private class FacebookPoster extends AsyncTask {
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      showToast(result);
      finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
      Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
      parameters.putString("message", messageToPost);
      parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
      try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
          return "Blank response.";
        } else {
            return "Message posted to your facebook wall!";
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ShareOnFacebook", e.getMessage());
        return "Failed to post to wall!";
      }
    }
  }

  public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
  }

  private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

This is the log, I don´t see the dialog for auth my acount...directly i see "Force close":

```
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2168)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2163)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     ... 11 more
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$drawable
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.createCrossImage(FbDialog.java:106)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.onCreate(FbDialog.java:81)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:814)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:343)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:206)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at abm.face.post.FacebookPostMessageActivity.loginAndPostToWall(FacebookPostMessageActivity.java:144)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at abm.face.post.FacebookPostMessageActivity.share(FacebookPostMessageActivity.java:98)
07-24 15:47:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     ... 14 more
```

My manifest, with the internet permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="abm.face.post" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".FacebookPostMessageActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

any solution please??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your crash is caused by the `FbDialog` trying to inflate the cross image you use to close it.

Things to double check:

- The image resource is present.
- the R.java file it is referencing exists (com.facebook.android.R$drawable) depending on how the tutorial project is supposed to be implemented you may need to use your project's R file.

Hope this helps.